# Is a set open/closed/compact/connected independent of the metric defined on it?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness

I'm wondering if a set is open/closed/compact/connected independent of the chosen metric. For example, if a set is compact, does that mean it's compact regardless of the metric defined? I think the answer is no but cannot come up with an example. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For example, the set $\{1\}$ is open with the [discrete metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) but not with the usual metric

Answer (score 2):

This is true if and only if the two metrics induce the same topology (simply by definition), which need not be true. For example, you can define a metric $d$ on the real numbers with $d(x, y) =1$ if $x\neq y$. Then every subset is open, which is certainly not true in the usual topology.

Comment: So if two metrics induce the same topology, all the results (openness etc.) are the same?

Comment: @Chris Yes that's right.

Comment: Appreciate!!!!!!